Повествование или описание?
В этом предложении представлено повествование или описание:

"Иван Петрович и Софья Александровна щелкают на счетах, а я сижу подле
них за своим столом и мажу — и мне тепло, покойно, и сверчок кричит".

Я вижу здесь описание, ведь все можно изобразить на одной картинке. Действия идут параллельно друг другу.
